# How to span long itemize on different frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I span the long item over slides not to skip to a new page to start a new item.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, t]{title}{}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Dans cet autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises). Il s'agit d'un synclinal.
  \item Dans cet autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises). Il s'agit d'un synclinal.
  \item Dans cet autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises). Il s'agit d'un synclinal. autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises). Il s'agit
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a sketch how the result should look like? Do you want the page break within the 3rd item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `\item[]` at the position where you want the page break to occur:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, t]{title}{}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Dans cet autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises). Il s'agit d'un synclinal.
  \item Dans cet autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises). Il s'agit d'un synclinal.
  \item Dans cet autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises).
  \item[] Il s'agit d'un synclinal. autre cas, le pendage des couches est différent : le flanc NE pend vers le SW et le flanc SW pend vers le NE. Le pli a une forme concave ("en creux"). En carte, les couches au centre de la structure sont les plus jeunes (couches grises). Il s'agit
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]